# Browser keep images in memory

Tags: c#, ajax, browser, web, memory-leaks

I have a **web application** that get images from the database and load in the screen with **ajax**.

The problem is: as I'm loading new images they will remaining in the memory of the browser (I don't know for sure if is in memory, cache or another place) and the memory used by the browser keeps growing.

Someone knows how to solve it? There is a way to "clean" this images from the browser before i start to get new images?

Answer (score 0):

One trick to get pass caching is to add a unique value to query string, so that browser will always load new version of the file i.e:

www.domaing.com/image.jpg?t=12345

I personally use (in server side) System.Environment.TickCount but it can be pretty much anything (like GUID)

Comment: Thanks but this ain't gonna help me. Cause the program already catches the new image. The problem is that the old one continues there and then the memory is increased!